# How to write struct to file in go or python?

Tags: python, go

In C/C++, we can write a struct to file like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct mystruct
{
    int i;
    char cha;
};

int main(void)
{
    FILE *stream;
    struct mystruct s;
    stream = fopen("TEST.$$$", "wb"))
    s.i = 0;
    s.cha = 'A';
    fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, stream); 
    fclose(stream); 
    return 0;
}
```

But how to wirte a struct to file in go or python ? I want the data in struct are continuous.

Comment: So do you want it in Go or python?

Comment: Python -- check `ctypes` or `struct.pack`, Golang -- use `encoding/binary`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python you can use `ctypes` module which allows you to generate structures with similar layout as C does, and convert them to byte arrays:

```
import ctypes

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('i', ctypes.c_int),
                ('cha', ctypes.c_char)]

s = MyStruct()
s.i = 0
s.cha = 'A'

f.write(bytearray(s))
```

There is a simplest approach in Python with using `struct.pack` and manually provide a layout as first argument (`'ic'` means `int` followed by a char):

```
import struct 
f.write(struct.pack('ic', 0, 'A'))
```

Go can encode structs via `encoding/binary`

```
type myStruct struct {
    i int 
    cha byte
}

s := myStruct{i: 0, cha:'A'}
binary.Write(f, binary.LittleEndian, &s)
```

**NOTE**: You will be subject of differing structure *alignment*, *padding* and *endianness*, so if you want to build truly interoperable program, use special formats such as [Google Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf)